# mod_rewrite conflict, two strings, and a file including others

Tags: php, algorithm, mod-rewrite, logic, structure

First ill explain how index.php is working in my site.

First, index.php has a function to filter GET name if is not null and exist a name (what i defined) for my pages, like blog, photos, modalities, about and contact so include the file that has the same name of request GET

My htacess works fine for single pages, like modalities, about, contact, but now i want add "subcategories", like blog/hello-world.

blog.php works same way of index, its include a file of same name from GET variable (post).

in others words, lets see in action.

index.php?page=modalities -> /modalities 
index.php?page=blog&post=nameofpost - > i can see correctly
but when use htaccess has a conflict with first rule, because it analyzes the blog as a single file and has no space to another GET variable

i want rewrite index.php?page=blog&post=nameofpost to /blog/nameofpost without conflict with first rule of rewrite.

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?pg=$1 [L]

if i use more strings in htacess of rewrite rule i cant use for my single pages like contact (index.php?pg=contact /contact) its give me a 404 error.

My index.php (structure)

```
$url =  addslashes($_GET["pg"]);

    if(isset($url) && ($url === "photos" || $url === "time" || $url === "modalities" || $url === "contact" || $url === "blog" || $url === "about")){

        include "page/{$url}.php";

        return $lock = true;
        }elseif($url === "" || $url === "home" || !isset($url) || (empty($url) || trim($url)==='')){

            include "home.php";


            }else{


                echo "Error 404";

                }
```

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?pg=$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404
ErrorDocument 403 /404
ErrorDocument 404 /404
Options -Indexes 
IndexIgnore *
```

i know .htaccess file is not configured, because i cant find a solution to do it, two type of url in same time.

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

The following RewriteRule will allow you to have two levels, rewriting the first part of the path as `pg=` and the rest of the path as `post=`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?pg=$1&post=$2 [L]
```

To ensure this doesn't interfere with your existing rule, you should change the existin `RewriteRule` to match anything that *isn't* a path seperator (`/`):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?pg=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't working, when i use slashes at end of string, for example, mysite.com/about/ its show the content (PHP) but its add a double path of my html, like style/style/site.css img/img/image01.jpg Its only works if i use first or second rule no both at same time, like you told two levels of rewrite.
RewriteRule ([^/]*) index.php?pg=$1 [L]
for single pages like modalities, about, contact....
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*) index.php?pg=$1&post=$2 [L]
and for pages with subpages, like blog, news etc...

Comment: I wasn't able to edit this during the weekend, so I've updated the answer now - it should (!!) work if you put both rules in your .htaccess file. It should cope with trailing slashes, too.

Comment: Glad for your atenttion, 'll test.